# Can I just glue the "fin" thing back onto my dryer?

Tags: dryer

Not sure the right name of the part, but it's one of the "fins" on the inside. One of them came off, and looking at it tells me there were screws going through the drum to hold it in. The screws fell out, and are presumably inside the dryer somewhere.

So basically two questions:

1. Is it going to cause problems if I just leave the screws inside the
   dryer?
2. Can I just use superglue or something to put that "fin" back
   in place?

Bonus Question: If I'm way better off getting the screws out and actually screwing it back in, how difficult would that be? Should I just find a repairman?

Comment: I wouldn't trust glue, heat and clothes together.  The only glue that comes to mind that would even be feasible would be a high temp epoxy.  But getting to the screws as well might be problematic as well.  I'm assuming the cloths drum spins inside another drum where the screws would be.  Getting that drum out might be a bit of work.  If you look up your model online you might find a repair manual which would detail how to dissemble.

Comment: Without knowing the make and model, it's difficult to say how difficult it would be to repair.

Comment: Many common Dryer parts are available online, at least in the US, through Amazon at competitive prices. Googling the make and model number typically provides diagrams and part numbers at other online vendors. Dryer repair is not particularly difficult.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Find the maintenance manual for your drier. (It may be online from the manufacturer, or there are services which will sell you a download for a few dollars). Unplug the drier, and follow the manufacturer's instructions for opening it up. You'll probably find yourself looking at the drum, with plenty of space to drive screws back in. (You may or may not find the lost screws in the bottom of the machine).

If you don't have sufficient space, follow the instructions for dismounting the drum. Re-affix the fin, then follow the instructions for reinstalling the drum.

Follow the instructions for closing the patient. Plug it back in and make sure it still runs. If not, take it apart again and figure out what you did wrong.

Comment: ...and you might want some threadlocker on the screws so you don't have to repeat this exercise.

Comment: ... and you may want to check the screws holding the other "fins" while you have the chance. Keep that threadlocker handy

Comment: If you are in this deep, you might want to get a drum drive belt and replace it while everything is apart.

Comment: Good suggestion, @mikes. Perfect opportunity for some preventative maintenance.